# Using the CRFBiasedClassifier

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, crf

I came across a class in Stanford's CoreNLP, the CRFBiasedClassifier. I'm wondering if there is any documentation on its use.

What I am trying to do is bias my classifier to be able to pick up more entities of my label A. After setting my `classBias` property to A:100, I am unable to get entities of label A picked up.

I have three labels: A, B & C
Currently, as I am checking it out, A has 40 occurrences, B has 70 and C has 100.

I am serializing the classifier as below:

```
SeqClassifierFlags flags = new SeqClassifierFlags(props);
CRFBiasedClassifier<CoreLabel> crf = new CRFBiasedClassifier<>(flags);
crf.train();

crf.serializeClassifier(modelOutPath);
```

And deserializing like this:

```
CRFClassifier<CoreLabel> model = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(MODELFILE);
```

If I try

```
CRFBiasedClassifier<CoreLabel> model = (CRFBiasedClassifier<CoreLabel>)CRFClassifier.getClassifier(MODELFILE);
```

I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier cannot be cast to edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFBiasedClassifier
```

Is there a better way to improve recall rate of my entities?